# Alternative to keydown event.keys condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, keydown, onkeydown

Obviously the code below is not ideal since there are so many separate conditions. However, it is difficult to imagine an inverse approach. Is there a better alternative?

```
if (!(Number(e.key)
|| e.key === '0'
|| e.key === '.'
|| e.key === 'Backspace'
|| e.key === 'ArrowLeft'
|| e.key === 'ArrowRight'
|| (e.getModifierState('Control') && e.key === 'a')
|| (e.getModifierState('Control') && e.key === 'c')
|| (e.getModifierState('Control') && e.key === 'v'))){
  return false
}
```

Comment: Wrapping all those in `!( /* all your conditions */)` would give you inverse

Comment: @charlietfl ah ok thx. r u aware of any shorter ways to write it?

Comment: Using keyCode would be a bit shorter than the strings. Good thing about the strings though is easier to know which is which. A `switch()` is another option

Comment: @charlietfl `keyCode` is deprecated

Comment: Ahh   wasn't aware of that. Haven't used it for a long time

Comment: Why did you add `!( )` to your code?

Comment: @melpomene i changed the code because i changed the question, although the question isnt much different